# Intro Probability Question 1 help needed

Tags: probability, statistics

Question:

You are deciding whether to purchase a lottery ticket that costs 10 dollars and would pay out 115 dollars. What would the probability of winning have to be for the expected value of your purchase to $0?

Can someone guide me thru this question

Comment: Recall the definition of expected value. Set the probability to win as $p$, write the expectation as an expression of $p$, and see what value of $p$ makes the expectation zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For future reference, [here's how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Following this might help reduce the downvotes and close votes you're getting on this question - perhaps include your thoughts and attempts so far.

Comment: sorry I was a little confused

Comment: Suppose the probability of winning is $1/200$  Can you compute your expectation?

Comment: @saulspatz is it possible to for you to show me how to solve this because my teacher never showed us how and I would be able to finish my other homework questions if I get a example of a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation from is the probability probability of winning times the amount that you win.  In this case, that's $$105p+(1-p)(-10)$$  There are two possible outcomes: you win the lottery and net $105$ (probability $p$)or you don't win and you are out the purchase price (probability $1-p$).

Now set the expectation equal to $0$ and solve for $p$.